# Insert data into REDIS (node.js + redis)

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

How, i can insert (store) data something like this (node.js + redis):

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

client.hmset('room:'+room, {
          'enabled' : true,
           timestamp : {
              'g1' : 0,
              'g2' : 0

           }
});
```

and how affter that i can do increment for g1 or g2 ?

P.S. when insert timestamp this way, redis-cli show timestamp instead UNIX time

Comment: [Isn't Unix time a timestamp?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You have other storage options if you don't mind the increased storage space. You could store time as a string, or even store the [date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) in redis. While I haven't done that personally, it should work just fine. I don't know which option works best for you, but personally I'd store a timestamp and convert to a date object when I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a combination of [HMGET](http://redis.io/commands/hmget) and [HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/hmset). According to [the docs](http://redis.io/commands):

> ### HMGET key field [field ...]
>
> Returns the values associated with the specified fields in the hash
>   stored at key.
>
> For every field that does not exist in the hash, a nil value is
>   returned. Because a non-existing keys are treated as empty hashes,
>   running HMGET against a non-existing key will return a list of nil
>   values.
>
> ### HMSET key field value [field value ...]
>
> Sets the specified fields to their respective values in the hash
>   stored at key. *This command overwrites any existing fields in the
>   hash*. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created.

What you want to do, then, is retrieve your value from the has, perform any operations on it that seem appropriate, and save over the previous value.

Another, possibly better solution, would be to use [HINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/hincrby). Provided you stick with a timestamp, you can increment the field without performing a get operation:

> ### HINCRBY key field increment
>
> Increments the number stored at field in the hash stored at key by
>   increment. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created.
>   If field does not exist the value is set to 0 before the operation is
>   performed.
>
> The range of values supported by HINCRBY is limited to 64 bit signed
>   integers.

You probably will need to restructure your hash for this to work though, unless there is a way to drill down to your g1/g2 fields (stackoverflow community, feel free to edit this answer or comment it if you know a way). A structure like this should work:

```
{
    enabled : true,
    timestamp_g1 : 0,
    timestamp_g2 : 0
}
```

Comment: *disclaimer*: I have only dabbled in Redis a little; I'll be getting more involved in the near future.

Comment: Then how i can make timestamp_g1 to 1377519643877_g1 or g1_1377519643877 ?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question. the property is called `timestamp_g1`, and the value of the property is an integer. Why do you need to add a prefix or suffix to the timestamp?

Comment: I rethinked, and i found another solution for what i need :) : room.g1.timestamp, count  and room.g2.timestamp, count

Comment: Glad to hear you figured out your naming scheme! If my answer was relevant to your question, be sure to mark it answered and up-vote any helpful comments to reward my efforts and allow the stackoverflow community to benefit :)